# Insufficient privileges to add Page Layout and Documents to change sets

Tags: change-set, insufficient-privileges

I'm trying to bring page layouts and documents into production with change sets, but I can't because SF says insufficient privilege. I'm using an admin profile and I have already created other change sets with objects, fields etc. without any problem. Anyone can help me ?

Comment: You are facing issues adding component to changeset or  when changeset gets uploaded in production?

Comment: when adding component to changeset.

Comment: Can you be specific in which component you are facing privilege issue? I think page layout shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: Yes, when I try to create a changeset and add Page Layout component, i'can't because it says I have not privilege but the strange thing is that I did not have this problem with the other components but only with Page Layout and Documents